# How do I base an if statement on a specific row index of a table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

Based on the last question, I have now managed to get the code working in a table on a site I'm creating. I now have to base some of the jQuery on if statements.

If the rows is before the "Senmiddelalder" row it should do some code
If the row IS "Senmiddelalder" it should do some other code
If the row is "Kolonitiden" it have to some other code
and lastly if the row is after "Kolonitiden" it have to do some other code

Now it just do the same regardless of which row I'm working on, and that is not what it should do.

I'm not the best at jQuery I should mention, but I'm trying hard to understand this.

If anyone could help I would appreciate it very much.

I have this code so far

```js
$(function(){
                        
            $("input").keyup(function(){
                var $currentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var $nextTr = $currentTr.next();
                var $prevTr = $currentTr.prev();
                var $nextTr2 = $nextTr.next();
                var $prevTr2 = $prevTr.prev();
                var value = $(this).val();
               
                
                if ($('tr:lt(5)')){
                    
                    $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value);
                    $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1 / 2);
                    $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 2);
                
                    if (value === '') {
                        $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                    }
                    
                }
                else if ($('tr:nth-child(6)')){
                    
                    $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value);
                    $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 3 / 4);
                    $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1 / 2);
                    $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 2);
                
                    if (value === '') {
                        $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                    }
                    
                }
                else if ($('tr:nth-child(7)')){
                    $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value);
                    $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 3 / 4);
                    $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1 / 2);
                    $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1.33);
                
                    if (value === '') {
                        $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                    }
                }
                else if ($('tr:gt(6)')) {
                    $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value);
                    $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 3 / 4);
                    $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1 / 2);
                    $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1.33);
                    $prevTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 2);
                
                    if (value === '') {
                        $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                        $prevTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
                    }
                }
                
                
            });
            
            $("input").click(function() {
                $("input").val("");
                $("tr td:nth-child(6)").empty();
            });
            
        });
    </script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table ID="tradeTable" class="tableTradeContent">
        <tr>
            <th>Tidsalder</th>
            <th>Billeder</th>
            <th>Varer</th>
            <th>Bedre lavere alternativ</th>
            <th>Bedre højere alternativ</th>
            <th>Resultat</th>
            <th>Antal</th>
            <th>Ratio</th>
            <th>pris / 24 timer</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bronzealder</td>
            <td><img src="img/BA/marmor.png"><img src="img/BA/tømmer.png"><img src="img/BA/farvestoffer.png"><img src="img/BA/sten.png"><img src="img/BA/vin.png"></td>
            <td>Marmor, Tømmer, Farvestoffer, Sten, Vin</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>400/400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jernalder</td>
            <td><img src="img/JA/stof.png"><img src="img/JA/ibenholt.png"><img src="img/JA/smykker.png"><img src="img/JA/jern.png"><img src="img/JA/kalksten.png"></td>
            <td>Stof, Ibenholt, Smykker, Jern, Kalksten</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>800/800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Tidlig Middelalder</td>
            <td><img src="img/TM/kobber.png"><img src="img/TM/guld.png"><img src="img/TM/granit.png"><img src="img/TM/honning.png"><img src="img/TM/alabast.png"></td>
            <td>Kobber, Guld, Granit, Honning, Alabast</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1600/1600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Højmiddelalder</td>
            <td><img src="img/HM/teglsten.png"><img src="img/HM/glas.png"><img src="img/HM/tørret urt.png"><img src="img/HM/tov.png"><img src="img/HM/salt.png"></td>
            <td>Teglsten, Glas, Tørret Urt, Tov, Salt</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>3200/3200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Senmiddelalder</td>
            <td><img src="img/SM/basalt.png"><img src="img/SM/messing.png"><img src="img/SM/krudt.png"><img src="img/SM/silke.png"><img src="img/SM/talkumpudder.png"></td>
            <td>Basalt, Messing, Krudt, Silke, Talkumpudder</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>6400/6400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Kolonitiden</td>
            <td><img src="img/KT/kaffe.png"><img src="img/KT/papir.png"><img src="img/KT/porcelæn.png"><img src="img/KT/tjære.png"><img src="img/KT/metaltråd.png"></td>
            <td>Kaffe, Papir, Porcelæn, Tjære, Metaltråd</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>9600/9600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Industritiden</td>
            <td><img src="img/IT/koks.png"><img src="img/IT/gødning.png"><img src="img/IT/gummi.png"><img src="img/IT/tekstiler.png"><img src="img/IT/hvalolie.png"></td>
            <td>Koks, Gødning, Gummi, Tekstiler, Hvalolie</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>12800/12800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Den Progressive Æra</td>
            <td><img src="img/DPÆ/asbest.png"><img src="img/DPÆ/sprængstoffer.png"><img src="img/DPÆ/maskindele.png"><img src="img/DPÆ/benzin.png"><img src="img/DPÆ/blik.png"></td>
            <td>Asbest, Sprængstoffer, Maskindele, Benzin, Blik</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>16000/16000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Moderne Æra</td>
            <td><img src="img/MÆ/færdigretter.png"><img src="img/MÆ/jernbeton.png"><img src="img/MÆ/smagsstoffer.png"><img src="img/MÆ/luksusmaterialer.png"><img src="img/MÆ/emballage.png"></td>
            <td>Færdigretter, Jernbeton, Smagsstoffer, Luksusmaterialer, Emballage</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>19200/19200 (*)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Den Postmoderne Tidsalder</td>
            <td><img src="img/DPT/genomdata.png"><img src="img/DPT/industrifilter.png"><img src="img/DPT/genanvendelige ressourcer.png"><img src="img/DPT/halvledere.png"><img src="img/DPT/stål.png"></td>
            <td>Genondata, Industrifilter, Genanvendelige Ressourcer, Halvledere, Stål</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>24000/24000 (*)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nutiden</td>
            <td><img src="img/NT/biometriske data.png"><img src="img/NT/elektromagneter.png"><img src="img/NT/gas.png"><img src="img/NT/plastik.png"><img src="img/NT/robotter.png"></td>
            <td>Biometriske Data, Elektromagneter, Gas, Plastik, Robotter</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>28800/28800 (*)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Morgendagen</td>
            <td><img src="img/MD/ernæringsforskning.png"><img src="img/MD/papirbeton.png"><img src="img/MD/konserveringsmidler.png"><img src="img/MD/intelligente materialer.png"><img src="img/MD/gennemskinneligt beton.png"></td>
            <td>Ernæringsforskning, Papirbeton, Konserveringsmidler, Intelligente Materialer, Gennemskinneligt Beton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>33600/33600 (*)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fremtiden</td>
            <td><img src="img/FT/alger.png"><img src="img/FT/bio-geokemiske data.png"><img src="img/FT/nanopartikler.png"><img src="img/FT/renset vand.png"><img src="img/FT/superleder.png"></td>
            <td>Alger, Bio-Kemiske Data, Nanopartikler, Renset Vand, Superledere</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>40000/40000 (*)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Arktiske Fremtid</td>
            <td><img src="img/AF/data om kunstig intelligens.png"><img src="img/AF/bioplastik.png"><img src="img/AF/nanotråd.png"><img src="img/AF/papirbatterier.png"><img src="img/AF/bio benzin.png"></td>
            <td>Data om Kunstig Intelligens, Bioplastik, Nanotråd, Papirbatterier, Bio Benzin</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>46800/46800 (*)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Oceanisk Fremtid</td>
            <td><img src="img/OF/kunstskæl.png"><img src="img/OF/biolys.png"><img src="img/OF/koraller.png"><img src="img/OF/perler.png"><img src="img/OF/plankton.png"></td>
            <td>Kunstskæl, Biolys, Koraller, Perler, Plankton</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>51600/51600 (*)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Virtuel Fremtid</td>
            <td><img src="img/VF/kryptovaluta.png"><img src="img/VF/datakrystaller.png"><img src="img/VF/guldris.png"><img src="img/VF/nanitter.png"><img src="img/VF/te silke.png"></td>
            <td>Kryptovaluta, Datakrystaller, Guldris, Nanitter, Te Silke</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input ID="input"></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>64000/64000 (*)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't like if statements. especially when using jquery on a html page.
so in your case, i would first start with adding classes to your table rows:

```
<tr class="preSenMiddel"> [...]
<tr class="senMiddel"> [...]
<tr class="kolonitiden"> [...]
<tr class="postKolonitiden"> [...]
```

you have to add the class to every tr tag. 
then make use of the jquery class selectors. every html attribute, that has a class assigned, can be selected as jquery object by using the expression: `$(".classname")`
(read more on jquery selectors here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
since your `<tr>` are the grand parent elements of your `<input>` elements, you then add the descendant selector to your expression. `$(".classname descendant")`

you could then create four different functions, that trigger, depending on the used input:

```
$(".preSenMiddel input").on("keyup", function(){
  //your code here
}
```

this has to be done for the other 3 classes, too...

in addition, if you add classes for every td - mainly just the column name, you don't need the `.find('td:nth-child(6)')` expression, but simply can select the element by it's class name. 
since you have your prev/next rows stored in jquery objects, you have to pass the object context with your selector.
this would change your code from:

```
 $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value);
```

to

```
$(".classname", $currentTr).html(value);
```

the good thing of the solution is, that you can freely change your table columns/row ordering as long as you keep the correct classes at the corresponding elements. 
in your solution, if you insert or remove a column, you'd have to change all your js nth child expression, to look at another index.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current row index and then can add conditions depends on that.
See example here

```
$(function(){
  $("input").keyup(function(){
    var $currentTr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $nextTr = $currentTr.next();
    var $prevTr = $currentTr.prev();
    var $nextTr2 = $nextTr.next();
    var $prevTr2 = $prevTr.prev();
    var value = $(this).val();
    if ($currentTr.index() < 5){
      //current row is less than Senmiddelalder
        $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value);
        $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1 / 2);
        $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 2);

        if (value === '') {
            $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
        }

    }
    else if ($currentTr.index() == 6){
        //current row is Kolonitiden
        $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value);
        $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 3 / 4);
        $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1 / 2);
        $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 2);

        if (value === '') {
            $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
        }

    }
    else if ($currentTr.index() == 7){
    //current row is Industritiden
        $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value);
        $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 3 / 4);
        $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1 / 2);
        $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1.33);

        if (value === '') {
            $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
        }
    }
    else if ($currentTr.index() > 6) {
    //current row is greater than Kolonitiden
        $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value);
        $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 3 / 4);
        $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1 / 2);
        $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 1.33);
        $prevTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html(value * 2);

        if (value === '') {
            $currentTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $nextTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $nextTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $prevTr.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
            $prevTr2.find('td:nth-child(6)').html("");
        }
    }


});

$("input").click(function() {
    $("input").val("");
    $("tr td:nth-child(6)").empty();
});

});
```

Notice comments added under if condition.
Also you should not use same id on the page for all inputs. `<input ID="input">`